# Reflection Line2D

Tags: 2d, raycasting, godot

I found a video on YouTube with a sercol and a beam, and everything seems to be fine, but the beam doubles and flickers after spawning from the mirror, tell me what could be the problem, screenshot and the code is attached.[image]
[image]

```
extends Node2D

onready var ray = $RayCast2D
onready var lain = $Node2D/Line2D

var vec = Vector2()
var max_bounces = 5

func _process(delta):
    lain.clear_points()
    
    vec.y-=1
    
    lain.add_point(Vector2.ZERO)
    
    ray.global_position = lain.global_position
    ray.cast_to = vec.normalized()*1000
    ray.force_update_transform()
    
    var prev = null
    var bounces = 0
    
    while true:
        if not ray.is_colliding():
            var pt = ray.global_position + ray.cast_to
            lain.add_point(lain.to_local(pt))
            break
        
        var coll = ray.get_collider()
        var pt = ray.get_collision_point()
        
        lain.add_point(lain.to_local(pt))
        
        if not coll.is_in_group("Mirrors"):
            break
            
        var normal = ray.get_collision_normal()
        
        if normal == Vector2.ZERO:
            break
        
        if prev !=null:
            prev.collision_mask = 3
            prev.collision_layer = 3
        prev = coll
        prev.collision_mask = 0
        prev.collision_layer = 0
        
        
        ray.global_position = pt
        ray.cast_to = ray.cast_to.bounce(normal)
        ray.force_raycast_update()
        
        bounces+=1
        if bounces >= max_bounces:
            break
        
    if prev !=null:
        prev.collision_mask = 3
        prev.collision_layer = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be calling `ray.force_raycast_update()` when you changed `ray.cast_to`, and you should be calling `ray.force_update_transform()` when you changed `ray.global_position`. Since you changing them together, call these together too. Here:

```
    ray.global_position = lain.global_position
    ray.cast_to = vec.normalized()*1000
    ray.force_update_transform()
    ray.force_raycast_update()
```

And here:

```
        ray.global_position = pt
        ray.cast_to = ray.cast_to.bounce(normal)
        ray.force_update_transform()
        ray.force_raycast_update()
```

And with that the flickering should be gone.

---

There are other improvements we can do to the code. Notably it mixes local and global coordinates. The reason being that `cast_to` is local to `ray`. Which means instead of this:

```
var pt = ray.global_position + ray.cast_to
```

You should do this:

```
var pt = ray.to_global(ray.cast_to)
```

And since we have the `normal` in global coordinates. This is not correct:

```
ray.cast_to = ray.cast_to.bounce(normal)
```

Instead, we are going to convert `ray.cast_to` to global, then bounce it, and back to local:

```
ray.cast_to = ray.to_local(ray.to_global(ray.cast_to).bounce(normal))
```

With that, you should be able to move or rotate your `Node2D` and the laser should go with it.

---

By the way, instead of switching collision layers and mask, you can add an exception to the ray with:

```
ray.add_exception(coll)
```

And remove it with:

```
ray.remove_exception(prev)
```

Ah, and if you want to clear the exception, you call `clear_exceptions`:

```
ray.clear_exceptions()
```

---

I also want to point out that every frame you decrement `vec.y`:

```
vec.y-=1
```

*If you keep decrementing `vec.y` it will eventually go out of representable integers.*

You probably want to just give a value once. Don't forget you are normalizing and then scaling by 1000 anyway:

```
ray.cast_to = vec.normalized()*1000
```

And yes, that is local of the `ray`. Which is why moving or rotating it should also move the ray.